# Turn An Unsorted Link List Into A Sorted Link List? (C++)

Tags: c++, list

I am having problems trying to turn the **INSERT** function into a function where it sorts the nodes alphabetically. I have written down what I've tried so far...but it only checks the name of the first node to see if it is bigger than the given name of the new node in the function's argument. Can someone please give me an idea of how I would be able to move through each node and be able to compare their keys (names) and place them left and right accordingly? Below is what I have in my code and my **INSERT** function so far...

```
  // UnSortedLnkList.h
    //----------------------------

    #include <iostream>
    #include <afxwin.h>

    using namespace std;

    #define new DEBUG_NEW

    struct Node  {
        string m_name;  // key
        int m_age;

        Node* m_next;
        Node(const string& name, int age, Node* next = NULL);
    };

    ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Node&);

    class ULnkList  {
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const ULnkList&); // 1.5
    public:
        ULnkList();
        // copy ctor
        ULnkList(const ULnkList& existingList );            // 5
        ~ULnkList();                                        // 4

        bool IsEmpty() const;
        int Size() const;
        bool Insert(const string& name, int age);           // 1
        bool Delete(const string& name);                    // 3
        bool Lookup(const string& name, int& age) const;    // 2

        ULnkList& operator =(const ULnkList& list2);        // 6

        bool Delete2(const string& name);   


    private:

        Node* m_head;   // points to head of the list
        int m_num;     // the number of entries in the list

        // helper functions:
        void Clear();                                       // 7
        void Copy(const ULnkList& list2);                   // 8
    };


    // UnSortedLnkList.cpp
    //----------------------------
    #include "UnSortedLnkList.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    Node::Node(const string& name, int age, Node* next)
    : m_name(name), m_age(age), m_next(next)
    {}


    ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Node& n)    // cout << n;
    {
        os << "Name: " << n.m_name << "\tAge: " << n.m_age;
        return os;
    }

    ULnkList::ULnkList()
    : m_head(new Node("",-99,NULL)), m_num(0)
    {
        //m_head = new Node("",-99,NULL);
    }
    //
    ULnkList::ULnkList(const ULnkList& existingList ) 
    {
        Copy(existingList);
    }

    void ULnkList::Copy(const ULnkList& existingList)
    {
        m_num = existingList.m_num;
        // create dummy node
        m_head = new Node("",-99,NULL);
        // traverse existing list
        Node *pe = existingList.m_head->m_next;
        Node *pThis = m_head;
        while( pe != 0)
        {
            // create a copy of the Node in OUR list
            pThis->m_next  = new Node(pe->m_name,pe->m_age,0);

            // update pointers
            pe = pe->m_next;
            pThis = pThis->m_next;
        }
    }

    void ULnkList::Clear()
    {
        Node *p = m_head->m_next;
        Node *tp = m_head;          // trail pointer
        while( p != 0)
        {
            delete tp;

            // update pointers
            tp = p;  // 
            p = p->m_next;
        }

        delete tp;
    }

    ULnkList& ULnkList::operator =(const ULnkList& list2)  // list1 = list2;
    {
        // list1 = list1;  // check for self-assignment
        if( this != &list2 )
        {
            this->Clear(); // normally Clear();
            this->Copy(list2);
        }

        // l1 = l2 = l3;

        return *this;
    }

    bool ULnkList::IsEmpty() const
    {
        return m_num == 0;
        // return m_head->m_next == NULL;
    }

    int ULnkList::Size() const
    {

        return m_num;
    }
    //

    ULnkList::Insert(const string& name, int age)
    {
        Node *current = m_head->m_next;
        Node *previous = m_head;
        if (m_head->m_next == NULL) 
        {
            m_head->m_next   = new Node(name,age,m_head->m_next); 
            m_num++;
            return true;
        }
        if (name < m_head->m_next->m_name)
        {
            m_head->m_next = new Node(name,age,m_head->m_next);
            m_num++;
            return true;
        }




        return true;
    }

    //
    ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const ULnkList& list) // cout << list;
    {
        Node *p = list.m_head->m_next; // first node with data

        while( p != 0 )
        {
            cout << *p << endl;  // ????

            // update p
            p = p->m_next;
        }
        cout << "--------------------------------------" << endl;

        return os;
    }

    //   input: name
    //// output: age if found
    bool ULnkList::Lookup(const string& name, int& age) const
    {
        // linear search
        Node *p = m_head->m_next;

        while( p != 0)
        {
            if( name == p->m_name )
            {
                // found it
                age = p->m_age;
                return true;
            }

            // update p
            p = p->m_next;
        }
        return false;
    }
    //
    bool ULnkList::Delete(const string& name)
    {
        Node *p = m_head->m_next;
        Node *tp = m_head;          // trail pointer
        while( p != 0)
        {
            if( name == p->m_name )
            {
                // found it, so now remove it
                // fix links
                tp->m_next = p->m_next;
                // delete the node
                delete p;

                return true;
            }

            // update pointers
            tp = p;  // tp = tp->m_next;
            p = p->m_next;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool ULnkList::Delete2(const string& name)
    {
        Node *p = m_head;
        while( p->m_next != 0 )     // ?????
        {
            if( p->m_next->m_name == name )
            {
                Node *save = p->m_next;
                // remove the node
                // fix links
                p->m_next = p->m_next->m_next;
                // delete memory
                delete save;
                return true;
            }

            // update pointers
            p = p->m_next;
        }
        return false;
    }
    //
    ULnkList::~ULnkList()
    {
        Clear();
    }
    //
```

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such. Otherwise, don't use a linked list to produce a crappy imitation of a `std::set` (well, I didn't look closely -- maybe it's a crappy imitation of an `std::multiset` instead). Oh, and since you're not writing templates, eradicate `this->` from your code too.

Answer (score 1):

I have a word of caution for this code

```
if(name > m_head->m_name ){
while(name > current->m_next->m_name){
    current = current->m_next;
}
// add temp = current->next
current->m_next = new Node(name,age)
// current->next->next = temp
```

You don't want to lose the list after where you insert.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is homework, so I'm not going to write the code. I would suggest that your Insert() function could walk the list from the head until it gets to the 'right' spot, by comparing the input string, and then doing the insert logic. That is assuming that you have to use a literal list as your data structure. If you want better insert performance on average, you could use a binary tree as your underlying structure, but that would make list traversal more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in this code:

```
    if (name < m_head->m_next->m_name)
    {
        m_head->m_next = new Node(name,age,m_head->m_next);
        m_num++;
        return true;
    }
```

In order to insert in a sorted manner, I would probably some sort of helper function with a recursive function call.

but this might work:

```
Node *current = m_head;
if(name > m_head->m_name ){
    while(name > current->m_next->m_name){
        current = current->m_next;
    }
    current->m_next = new Node(name,age,current->m_next);
}
else{
    m_head = new Node(name,age,m_head);
}
```

This will insert in an ascendingly sorted manner.
I haven't tested it,  but let me know if it works! hope this helps!